# how can I parse alamofire return json to the array of strings in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire, swifty-json

In my `swift` app I'm using `SwiftyJSON` and `Alamofire`.

I have a json that comes back from my backend to the application:

```
{
  "responses" : [
    {
      "labelAnnotations" : [
        {
          "mid" : "\/m\/01yrx",
          "score" : 0.8735667499999999,
          "description" : "cat"
        },
        {
          "mid" : "\/m\/0l7_8",
          "score" : 0.7697883,
          "description" : "floor"
        },
        {
          "mid" : "\/m\/01c34b",
          "score" : 0.7577944,
          "description" : "flooring"
        },
        {
          "mid" : "\/m\/03f6tq",
          "score" : 0.52875614,
          "description" : "living room"
        },
        {
          "mid" : "\/m\/01vq3",
          "score" : 0.52516687,
          "description" : "christmas"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to construct an array of `Strings` that contains each description mentioned above.
I tried to parse it with code:

```
{
    case .success:
      print("sukces")


      if let jsonData = response.result.value {

        let data = JSON(jsonData)
            print(data)

        if let responseData = data["responses"] as? JSON{

            if let responseData2 = responseData["labelAnnotations"] as? JSON{
                for userObject in responseData2 {
                    print(userObject["description"])
                }
            }

        }

    }

     case .failure(let error):
        print("fail")
        print(error)
    }
}
```

but line `print(userObject)` returns empty String. How can I display each description? As soon as I can print it in the console I will add it to my array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking if dictionary values are of `JSON` type seems to be the problem here because all [`SwiftyJSON`](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) does is to save you to trouble of doing type checking using `as? ...`.

I am not familiar with the library but I think all you have to do is:

*(Assuming `response.result.value` returns a dictionary since you've used `.responseJSON` method like `Alamofire.request(...).responseJSON(...)` otherwise you'll have to do `JSON(data: $0.data)` if you've called [`.response(...)`](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#response-handler) instead.)*

```
Alamofire.request(...).responseJSON { response in
  if let dictionary = response.result.value {
    let JSONData = JSON(dictionary)
    let userObjects =  JSONData["responses"][0]["labelAnnotations"].arrayValue.map( 
      { $0["description"].stringValue }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: swiftyJson is not a solution if you want to produce a proper array list in order to cache or use UserDefaults to store in plist.

Comment: @OnderOZCAN what's the question have to do with SwiftyJSON not being suitable for caching content or any other stuff? I think the library is mainly used just for dealing data convertible to JSON objects.